# Circumnavigating a curve or going through it to show different behavior

Tags: manipulate, locator

I am not sure if what I want to do is possible in *Mathematica*. I've provided something simple below to convey what I want to do. 
Basically what I want to happen is that when the `Locator` crosses over the blue line, the `Disk[]` will turn red and stay red until the `Locator` crosses the blue line again (it should stay red regardless of where the `Locator` is).

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[x^3, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1.5}, {0, 1.5}}, Frame -> True,
  Epilog -> 
   Inset[Graphics[{Blue, Disk[]}, ImageSize -> 30], {0.2, 1}]],
 {{comp, {0.5, 0.7}}, Locator}]
```

[image]

I am trying to make a Demonstration that shows the behavior of a single component (water in this case) on a pressure vs. temperature phase diagram. Water exists in 3 distinct phases and there is only a phase change from liquid to vapor (or supercritical) if a certain boundary is crossed (looks like the one I showed here) but you can go around that boundary and not change phase. So that's what I am trying to show here with the colored disk as the indicator of "phase change"

EDIT:

```
Manipulate[
 DynamicModule[{col = False, acc = 0, p = {420, Log[6]}},
  EventHandler[Show[Quiet@LogPlot[Log[T], {T, 273.16, 647.096}, PlotStyle -> Thick] /. 
     l_Line :> EventHandler[l, {"MouseEntered" :> If[acc === 0, 
(col = col /. {True -> False, False -> True})]}],
    Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{273.16, 700}, {Log[5.6], Log[7]}}, 
    Epilog -> 
     Inset[Graphics[
       Text[Style[Dynamic@If[col == True, "liquid", "vapor"], 18], 
        Scaled[{0.400, 0.1}]]]]],
   {"MouseDown" :> (acc = 1; MousePosition[Dynamic@p]), 
    "MouseDragged" :> (MousePosition[Dynamic@p]), 
    "MouseUp" :> (acc = 0; MousePosition[Dynamic@p])}, 
   PassEventsDown -> True]],
 {{p, {420, Log[6]}}, Locator, 
  Appearance -> Graphics[{Disk[]}, ImageSize -> 12]}]
```

It will only work if the mouse is *not* depressed.

Comment: What is the problem, it seems you've changed `If[acc === 1,` to `If[acc === 0,` on purpose. P.s. in case of `True/False` you can just use `col = !col` instead of rules.

Comment: I will try that. The reason I messed with If[acc===1 was because nothing at all worked with that definition for some reason. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to handle parallel `Events` but if there is single `Locator` you can try this:

```
DynamicModule[{col = Blue, acc = 0, p = {1, 1}},
 EventHandler[
  Show[
   Graphics[{Dynamic@Disk[p, Scaled@.03]}],
   Plot[x^3, {x, 0, 1}] /. l_Line :> EventHandler[ l, {"MouseEntered" :> 
                   If[acc === 1, (col = col /. {Red -> Blue, Blue -> Red})]}]
   , Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 1.5}, {0, 1.5}}, 
   Epilog -> Inset[Graphics[Dynamic@{col, Disk[]}, ImageSize -> 30], {0.2, 1}]
   ],
  {"MouseDown" :> (acc = 1; p = MousePosition["Graphics"]), 
   "MouseDragged" :> (p = MousePosition["Graphics"]),
   "MouseUp" :> (acc = 0;)}, PassEventsDown -> True]
 ]
```

[image]

Do not move cursor too quickly :P

The order of things in `Show` is important. Our custom locator has to be under the border line.

Comment: Thank you! This is simple and works...well mostly. It only works in my other program it the mouse is NOT depressed haha.

Comment: @baumannr could you say more, maybe I can help? (*not today since I have to go but in near future :)*)

Comment: In your solution, when you have the button on the mouse depressed and move the black circle across the line x^3, the color of the other disk changes. In the code that I worked this into, if I "click" and hold the mouse and then drag the cursor over the line, it won't work. It does work properly only if I just scroll over the line (without ever having clicked the mouse). I've made a number of desperate attempts to correct it but no luck. I will post an update with code a bit more similar to what I am using in case that makes any difference. Thank you so much! No rush.

Comment: @baumannr I will take a look at this tomorrow. If your update can change the context so those answers are not valid anymore please consider posting another question. Cya

Answer (score 11):

One way to detect crossings is to form a straight line between the previous position of the locator and the new position, and then check if there is an intersection between that straight line and $x^3$. I wrote this function to count the number of line intersection of a straight line with endpoints `p1` and `p2`. The function which in this case is $x^3$ can be any function, and the interval which in this case is $0<x<1$ can be any interval.

```
SetAttributes[countIntersections, HoldFirst]
countIntersections[{f_, {xmin_, xmax_}}, p1_, p2_] := Module[{delta = p2 - p1, sol},
  If[p1 == p2, Return[0]];
  sol = Solve[{
     {x, f} == p1 + Normalize[delta] k,
     # < x < #2 & @@ Sort[{First[p1], First[p1 + delta]}],
     xmin < x < xmax,
     0 < k < Norm[delta]
     }, {x, k}];
  Length@sol
  ]
```

Just to emphasize how this work I built a little demo.

```
DynamicModule[{p1 = {0.5, 0.5}, p2 = {0.6, 0.5}},
 LocatorPane[
  Dynamic[{p1, p2}],
  Dynamic@Show[
    Plot[x^3, {x, 0, 1}],
    Graphics[{
      If[
       countIntersections[{x^3, {0, 1}}, p1, p2] == 0,
       Black,
       Red
       ],
      Line[{p1, p2}]
      }]
    ]
  ]
 ]
```

[image: First demo]

But of course for the real thing we don't have two locators. The second position is simply the previous position of the locator. Here's how that can be written:

```
DynamicModule[{p1 = {0.5, 0.5}, p2, plot, diskColor = Black},
 p2 = p1;
 LocatorPane[
  Dynamic[p1],
  Dynamic[
   If[
     countIntersections[{x^3, {0, 1}}, p1, p2] != 0,
     diskColor = diskColor /. {Red -> Black, Black -> Red}
     ]
    plot = Show[
      Plot[x^3, {x, 0, 1}],
      Graphics[{
        diskColor,
        Disk[{0.2, 1}, 0.08]
        }], AspectRatio -> 0.75, PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 1.5}}
      ];
   p2 = p1;
   plot
   ]
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Second demo]

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer: this does not handle the going-around-the-curve bit.

```
 g1 = Graphics[{Blue, Table[Circle[{0, 0}, i], {i, 3}]}, ImageSize -> 20];
 g2 = Graphics[{Red, Table[Circle[{0, 0}, i], {i, 3}]},  ImageSize -> 20];

 DynamicModule[{pt = {0.1, 1}},
    Plot[x^3, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1.5}, {0, 1.5}}, 
       Filling -> Bottom, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 600,
       Epilog -> Dynamic@{
          If[Last[pt] < First[pt]^3, Blue, Red], PointSize[.05], Point[{.1, 1}],
          Locator[Dynamic[pt], If[Last[pt] < First[pt]^3, g1, g2]]}]]
```

[image]

[image]